# Fastest iterating of concurrent collections?

Tags: c#, collections

I have a conundrum, I need to iterate over the following data structure:

```
public ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentBag<string>> BaseCollection { get; set; }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Test Data:
    ConcurrentBag<string> One = new ConcurrentBag<string>() { "0", "1", "3", "5", "7", "9" };
    ConcurrentBag<string> Two = new ConcurrentBag<string>() { "0", "2", "4", "6", "8", "10" };
    ConcurrentBag<string> Three = new ConcurrentBag<string>() { "0", "10", "20", "30", "40" };

    // Init new Index:
    BaseCollection = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentBag<string>>();
    BaseCollection[0] = One;
    BaseCollection[1] = Two;
    BaseCollection[2] = Three;
}



private void Find_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // 3 Dictionary Items:
    var Items = BaseCollection.Select((k, v) => new { k, v });

   // I am a little stuck...
   // We should only find "0" and "10"
   // Knowing we need to look for "0" I can use the following to find it's frequency using:
   var Item = Items.SelectMany(i => i.k.Value).Select(a => a).Where(a => a == "0");
}
```

Say Five Dictionary Items with up to thousands of ConcurrentBags of strings

I need to find String Matches between Dictionary collections.

I thought about nested for loops, I thought about Linq, but I am not very skilled at Linq:

```
BaseCollection.Select((k, v) => new { k, v }).Where((k, v) => k.k.Value == k.k.Value);
```

If someone can point me in the right direction, so I can think about this in the best way. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered Hash Tables?

Comment: no, but an option if its fast and thread safe

Comment: HashMaps (more common IMO) are not thread safe, however HashTables should be. They are fairly slow but have the benefit of NOT increase time complexity on large lookups. IE Each look up takes a static amount of time, where most lookups will take longer with more entries.

Comment: What's the purpose of the program? Are you intending to merge the lists, or just note duplicates, or something else?

Comment: My example is an example of Data Structure. I have Dictionary Items, the int value, respresenting a Number, this is for another part of the application, cataloging Parts, the ConcurrentBags are part numbers. I need to delete duplicates, keeping only one item.

Comment: I think this question needs more work. You will have to explain how you need this sorted, if you are merging the results of the bags (and they need to be sorted), how are you are adding and accessing the bags, and why and how concurrency is a problem. Without some of these constraints its really hard to give you a concrete solution

Comment: (1) Are `string`s filling the bags for proof of concept simplicity? i.e. will be a different class in production? (2) *String Matches between Dictionary collections.* - that `Find_Click()` method shell makes me think you might mean "within a given dictionary find duplicate strings across element keys" (3) ... all that makes me wonder about the key's structure/type/class itself. (4) ... and that has implications for possibly preventing duplicates at "Add() time"

Comment: I) Yes, an Id will be used.
2) Yes, Duplicates between Dictionary Items, within each Concurrent Bag.
3) Existing Dataset is the problem, but yes, already incorporated in my side, error or duplicate checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a list of unique entries across all of the `ConcurrentBag`s:

```
var IDs = BaseCollection.SelectMany(u => u.Value);
var duplicateIDs = IDs.Distinct().ToList();
```

If you want those that appear more than once:

```
var IDs = BaseCollection.SelectMany(u => u.Value);
var multipleTimes = IDs
    .GroupBy(z => z)
    .Where(z => z.Count() > 1)
    .Select(z => z.Key)
    .ToList();
```

`SelectMany` does a projection to get all entries across all of the `ConcurrentBag`s. `Distinct` removes duplicates. `GroupBy` and `Where` allows filtering by how many matches there are. `ToList` outputs the results as a `List<int>`.

```
.Where(z => z.Count() > 1)
```

could also be replaced with:

```
.Where(z => z.AtLeast(2))
```

if you use [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/). *You'd need to profile the code (over a number of calls) to see whether it improves performance or not.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, after much confusion, an answer of sorts has been worked out.

With NO error checking or duplicate checking:

```
private void Find_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var IDs = BaseCollection.SelectMany(u => u.Value);

    foreach (string id in IDs)
    {
        var Items = BaseCollection.Select((k, v) => new { k, v });
        var Item = Items.SelectMany(i => i.k.Value).Select(a => a).Where(a => a == id);

        int Count = Item.Count();

        if(Count > 1) // Duplicate Found, Figure out what to do...
    }
}
```

I am sure this can be greatly improved for both speed and accuracy.

Comment: Not marking as answer as I think this could be greatly improved.