# C# Linq getting incorrect results from ToDictionary

Tags: c#

I have some code, looking for matches, an answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093182/fastest-iterating-of-concurrent-collections/53094661#53094661) gives some history behind this question. I am looking at a dataset, sorting and finding matches.

My example:

```
// Test Data:
ConcurrentBag<string> One = new ConcurrentBag<string>() { "0", "1", "3", "5", "7", "9" };
ConcurrentBag<string> Two = new ConcurrentBag<string>() { "0", "2", "4", "6", "8", "10" };
ConcurrentBag<string> Three = new ConcurrentBag<string>() { "0", "10", "20", "30", "40" };

// Init new Index:
BaseCollection = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentBag<string>>();
BaseCollection[0] = One;
BaseCollection[1] = Two;
BaseCollection[2] = Three;

// Get all Id's in this Collection:
var IDs = BaseCollection.SelectMany(u => u.Value);

// Sort and extract Matches:
var Matches = IDs.GroupBy(id => id)
                 .Where(id => id.Count() > 1)
                 .Select(id => id.Key).Distinct()
                 .ToDictionary(id => id.ToString(), id => id.Count());
```

I get:

```
0: 1
10: 2
```

I should get:

```
0: 3
10: 2
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `id` here is a `string`:

```
.ToDictionary(id => id.ToString(), id => id.Count());
```

So it doesn't represent the collection as you think it does. Calling count returns the number of characters instead of the number of times an item is occurred.

You should change your LINQ query to use actual group rather than the key:

```
IDs.GroupBy(id => id)
   .Where(id => id.Count() > 1)
   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: Ah, damn, I should have thought of that, thank you so much!